# PDF for sum of uniform variables in sympy.stats module

Tags: python, probability, probability-density

The problem statement is the following:
let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be uniformly distributed variables over $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$, find the pdf representing $Z = X_1 + X_2$. In sympy.stats they only have a built in function, UniformSum, for uniform variables all over $(0,1)$.

The question is then: Can this pdf be found with the sympy.stats module or is it currently not at a point where that is a possibility? If it can be done, how?

I tried the following:

```
X_1 = Uniform('X_1',0,1)

X_2 = Uniform('X_2',0,2)

Z = X_1 + X_2

density(Z)(z)
```

Which produced a huge piece of nonsense (to me atleast)

Comment: Dunno about Sympy, but, having worked on this problem with another system (Maxima), I would say the difficult part is handling the piecewise defined density functions. Maybe one way to make progress is to explicitly define the integrand in terms of functions defined piecewise instead of using the predefined uniform density. As you may know already, the result of the convolution of such densities should be piecewise-defined polynomials, with the degree of the polynomials equal to n - 1, where n is the number of uniform variables which have been summed.

Comment: I looked into how sympy sets up the pdf for the uniform variables in the first place, it uses a piecewise defined function like the one from sympy Piecewise(). So I'm not sure if that's an avenue that will pan out! Maybe I could try to define them from (0,1), (1,2), to help sympy's convolution calculator.

Answer (score 2):

This code will calculate and simplify the PDF of the sum of X_1 and X_2. The resulting pdf_Z_simplified will represent the probability density function of Z = X_1 + X_2.

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
from sympy.stats import Uniform, density
from sympy.stats.drv_types import TransformedDensity

# Define the random variables
X_1 = Uniform('X_1', 0, 1)
X_2 = Uniform('X_2', 0, 2)

# Define the variable for the sum
z = symbols('z')

# Calculate the PDF of the sum
pdf_Z = density(X_1 + X_2)(z)

# Simplify the PDF
pdf_Z_simplified = pdf_Z.simplify()

print(pdf_Z_simplified)
```

Comment: when i try this code the line "from sympy.stats.drv_types import TransformedDensity" gives me an error: " cannot import name 'TransformedDensity' from 'sympy.stats.drv_types' "

Comment: Even after removing Transformed density, I'm getting back some ugly integrals with Mejer G function. Could you post what the fixed code prints?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it analytically, by various means. The easiest is to first find the cumulative density function and then differentiate. The cdf is the double integral over the area in the x-y plane such that x+y<=Z of the product of pdfs of X and Y (just 1/2 in this instance, so the overall double integral would just be 1/2 times area). You can just draw it and find the areas of triangles or trapezia.

The result is a multi-part pdf:

(1/2)z ,  if z<=1

(1/2) ,  if 1<=z<=2

(1/2)(3-z) ,  if 2<=z<=3

0 everywhere else.

Comment: I already know the answer, as I should've stated in the original question, I'm only interested in ways to make sympy's stats module obtain the result for this and potentially other thougher questions like this one. Thank you for your input though! :))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's write about how it could be done. Take U01 PDf and compute Fourier transform F[U01] of it, aka characteristic function. Then for RVs sum compute F[U01]*F[U01] and compute inverse transform, that will get you PDF of sum

PDFsum = Fi[F[U01]*F[U01]]

That is simple consequence of the convolution theorem.

Tried this in SymPy, and it was able to get F[U01] but unable to get inverse

```
import sympy as sp

xr = sp.Symbol('xr', real = True)
wr = sp.Symbol('wr', real = True)

u01 = sp.Function('u01')
fu01 = sp.Function('fu01')

u01 = (sp.sign(xr) + sp.sign(1-xr))/2

fu01 = sp.fourier_transform(u01, xr, wr)
print(fu01)

q = sp.inverse_fourier_transform(fu01*fu01, wr, xr)
print(q)
```

From the other hand, Mathematica was able to get the answer. Maybe you could massage SymPy code to do something. Mathematica code below

```
U01[x_] := (Sign[x] + Sign[1 - x])/2
CF = FourierTransform[U01[x], x, w, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
CFU01[w_] := CF

PDF1 = InverseFourierTransform[CFU01[w], w, x, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
PDFsum = InverseFourierTransform[CFU01[w]^2, w, x, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
```

and then

```
Plot[PDFsum, {x, -1.6, 3.6}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

produced

[image]

UPDATE

Looks like I missed you want U01 and U02. Here is updated Mathematica code using convolution via Fourier transform method. SymPy is still no go

```
U01[x_] := (Sign[x] + Sign[1 - x])/2
U02[x_] := (Sign[x] + Sign[2 - x])/4
CFU01[w_] := FourierTransform[U01[x], x, w, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
CFU02[w_] := FourierTransform[U02[x], x, w, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
PDFU01 = InverseFourierTransform[CFU01[w], w, x, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
PDFU02 = InverseFourierTransform[CFU02[w], w, x, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
PDFsum =  InverseFourierTransform[CFU01[w] CFU02[w], w, x, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
Plot[PDFsum, {x, -0.6, 3.6}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

produced

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I looked into mathematica aswell (seeing as i would like to be able to compute questions like theese at my exam) and got the right pdf by the following: `pdfofsum[x_] := integrate[PDF[UniformDistribution[ {0,1}], u] * PDF[UniformDistribution[{0,2}, x-u], {u, 0, x}, Assumptions -> {0 <= x <= 3}];` but I feel like sympy should be able to compute this as well, there's just something I'm missing!

Comment: @ErikRoss-Rønnow Yep, got the same feeling - should be computable but it isn't, and there is something I missed

Comment: @ErikRoss-Rønnow Updated with proper distributions